# Trigger AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE to call stored procedure with table name and primary key

Tags: sql-server, triggers

For a sync process, my SQL Server database should record a list items that have changed - table name and primary key.

The DB already has a table and stored procedure to do this:

```
EXEC @ErrCode = dbo.SyncQueueItem "tableName", 1234;
```

I'd like to add triggers to a table to call this stored procedure on INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE.  How do I get the key?  What's the simplest thing that could possibly work?

```
CREATE TABLE new_employees
(
    id_num INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    fname VARCHAR(20),
    minit CHAR(1),
    lname VARCHAR(30)
);
GO

IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.sync_new_employees','TR') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TRIGGER sync_new_employees;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER sync_new_employees
ON new_employees
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
     DECLARE @Key Int;
     DECLARE @ErrCode Int;

     --  How to get the key???
     SELECT @Key = 12345; 

     EXEC @ErrCode = dbo.SyncQueueItem "new_employees", @key;
GO
```

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever We're all smart here.  You're going to have to pose harder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best solution, but just a **direct answer on the question**:

```
SELECT @Key = COALESCE(deleted.id_num,inserted.id_num);
```

Also **not the best way (if not the worst)** (do not try this at home), but at least **it will help with multiple values**:

```
DECLARE @Key INT;
DECLARE triggerCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY 
    FOR SELECT COALESCE(i.id_num,d.id_num) AS [id_num]
        FROM inserted i
        FULL JOIN deleted d ON d.id_num = i.id_num
        WHERE (
                COALESCE(i.fname,'')<>COALESCE(d.fname,'')
             OR COALESCE(i.minit,'')<>COALESCE(d.minit,'')
             OR COALESCE(i.lname,'')<>COALESCE(d.lname,'')
        )
;

OPEN triggerCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM triggerCursor INTO @Key;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC @ErrCode = dbo.SyncQueueItem 'new_employees', @key;
    FETCH NEXT FROM triggerCursor INTO @Key;
END

CLOSE triggerCursor;
DEALLOCATE triggerCursor;
```

Better way to use trigger based "value-change-tracker":

```
INSERT INTO [YourTableHistoryName] (id_num, fname, minit, lname, WhenHappened)
SELECT COALESCE(i.id_num,d.id_num) AS [id_num]
    ,i.fname,i.minit,i.lname,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS [WhenHeppened]
FROM inserted i
FULL JOIN deleted d ON d.id_num = i.id_num
WHERE ( COALESCE(i.fname,'')<>COALESCE(d.fname,'')
    OR COALESCE(i.minit,'')<>COALESCE(d.minit,'')
    OR COALESCE(i.lname,'')<>COALESCE(d.lname,'')
)
;
```

**The best (in my opinion) way to track changes is to use Temporal tables (SQL Server 2016+)**

Comment: Its considered bad coding practice to only handle the case of a single record insert/update/delete.

Comment: I know. Probably it was bad idea to answer directly to the asked question.

Comment: @MichaelCole - I trust you are aware that this is not a good solution - if you ever operate on more than a single row it won't work.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 4):

The way to access the records changed by the operation is by using the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo-tables that are provided to you by SQL Server.

`Inserted` contains any inserted records, or any updated records with their new values.

`Deleted` contains any deleted records, or any updated records with their old values.

[More Info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-2017)

When writing a trigger, to be safe, one should always code for the case when multiple records are acted upon. Unfortunately if you need to call a SP that means a loop - which isn't ideal.

The following code shows how this could be done for your example, and includes a method of detecting whether the operation is an Insert/Update/Delete.

```
declare @Key int, @ErrCode int, @Action varchar(6);

declare @Keys table (id int, [Action] varchar(6));

insert into @Keys (id, [Action])
  select coalesce(I.id, D.id_num)
    , case when I.id is not null and D.id is not null then 'Update' when I.id is not null then 'Insert' else 'Delete' end
  from Inserted I
  full join Deleted D on I.id_num = D.id_num;

while exists (select 1 from @Keys) begin
  select top 1 @Key = id, @Action = [Action] from @Keys;
  exec @ErrCode = dbo.SyncQueueItem 'new_employees', @key;
  delete from @Keys where id = @Key;
end
```

Further: In addition to solving your specified problem its worth noting a couple of points regarding the bigger picture.

1. As @Damien_The_Unbeliever points out there are built in mechanisms to accomplish change tracking which will perform much better.
2. If you still wish to handle your own change tracking, it would perform better if you could arrange it such that you handle the entire recordset in one go as opposed to carrying out a row-by-row operation. There are 2 ways to accomplish this a) Move your change tracking code inside the trigger and don't use a SP. b) Use a "User Defined Table Type" to pass the record-set of changes to the SP.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the **Magic Table** to get the data.
Usually, **inserted and deleted tables are called Magic Tables** in the context of a trigger. There are Inserted and Deleted magic tables in SQL Server. These tables are automatically created and managed by SQL Server internally to hold recently inserted, deleted and updated values during DML operations (Insert, Update and Delete) on a database table.

**Inserted magic table**

The Inserted table holds the recently inserted values, in other words, new data values. Hence recently added records are inserted into the Inserted table.

**Deleted magic table**

The Deleted table holds the recently deleted or updated values, in other words, old data values. Hence the old updated and deleted records are inserted into the Deleted table.

**You can use the inserted and deleted magic table to get the value of id_num **

```
 SELECT top 1 @Key = id_num from inserted
```

Note: This code sample will only work for a single record for insert scenario. For Bulk insert/update scenarios you need to fetch records from inserted and deleted table stored in the temp table or variable and then loop through it to pass to your procedure or you can pass a table variable to your procedure and handle the multiple records there.

Comment: I guess you're assuming/implying the use of some form of loop to handle multiple records right?

Comment: @Dale Burrell, yes, thanks, let me update my answer.

Comment: Its considered bad coding practice to only handle the case of a single record insert/update/delete.

Comment: Agreed, This is just a sample code to explain it,  I have given my upvote to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

A DML trigger should operate **set** data else only one row will be processed. It can be something like this. And of course use **magic tables** `inserted` and `deleted`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_employees 
   ON  dbo.employees --the table from Northwind database
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        declare @tbl table (id int identity(1,1),delId int,insId int)

        --Use "magic tables" inserted and deleted
        insert @tbl(delId, insId)
        select d.EmployeeID, i.EmployeeID
        from inserted i --empty when "delete"
        full join deleted d --empty when "insert"
            on i.EmployeeID=d.EmployeeID

        declare @id int,@key int,@action char

        select top 1 @id=id, @key=isnull(delId, insId),
            @action=case 
                when delId is null then 'I' 
                when insId is null then 'D' 
                else 'U' end --just in case you need the operation executed
        from @tbl
        --do something for each row
        while @id is not null --instead of cursor
        begin
            --do the main action
            --exec dbo.sync 'employees', @key, @action
            --remove processed row
            delete @tbl where id=@id
            --refill @variables
            select top 1 @id=id, @key=isnull(delId, insId),
                @action=case 
                    when delId is null then 'I' 
                    when insId is null then 'D' 
                    else 'U' end --just in case you need the operation executed
            from @tbl
        end
END
```

Answer (score 0):

inserted/deleted in triggers will generate as many rows as touched and calling a stored proc per key would require a cursor or similar approach per row.
You should check timestamp/rowversion in SQL Server. You could add that to the all tables in question (not null, auto increment, unique within database for each table/row etc).
You could add a unique index on that column to all tables you added the column.
@@DBTS is the current timestamp, you can store today's @@DBTS and tomorrow you will scan all tables from that to current @@DBTS. timestamp/rowversion will be incremented for all updates and inserts but for deletes it won't track, for deletes you can have a delete only trigger and insert keys into a different table.
Change data capture or change tracking could do this easier, but if there is heavy volumes on the server or large number of data loads, partition switches scanning the transaction log becomes a bottleneck and in some cases you will have to remove change data capture to save the transaction log from growing indefinetely.